# Inject new mothod to datepicker widget inside jQuery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to inject a new method into jquery. Basically, I have a datepicker loaded from the jQuery min file. Now, I want to inject a new method dateCompliance() whenever this datepicker is loaded.

```
   $("#ID").datepicker({
       onClose: removeAria,
       showOn: 'button',
       buttonImageOnly: false,
     })
  dateCompliance();// this is what I want to load along with datepicker everytime it loads. this is coming from another datecode.js file.
```

thank you , for tips on this!

Answer (score 0):

Create a basic jQuery plugin and do both datepicker initialization and custom function calling within it, whenever you want to initialize datepicker call the custom plugin.

```
$.fn.customDatepicker = function(option) {
  // within plugin code this refers to jQuery object of the element
  // initialize datepicker with the options
  this.datepicker(option);
  // call the function
  dateCompliance();
  // return jQuery object reference for chaining 
  return this;
};
```

and use the following code to initialize datepicker.

```
$("#ID").customDatepicker({
   onClose: removeAria,
   showOn: 'button',
   buttonImageOnly: false,
})
```

[JQuery documentation for basic plugin creation.](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Comment: Thank you @Pranav C Balan for the pointers. I'm currently working on implementing something similar. Will keep posted on how successful it went soon.